# How to call a secure proxy service via simple proxy service in WSO2 ESB

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-esb

I have made a secure proxy service in WSO2 ESB. I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.thilinamb.com/2011/02/invoking-secured-web-service-with.html). 
Now i want to call this service by using another proxy service. But when i send request from SoapUI to simple proxy service, i encountered an error. What i am unable to figure out is that how to pass security configurations to the proxy service.

**Note:** I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.

**Secure Proxy Service Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EchoProxy2"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="InSequence Log"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="Out Sequence Called"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://wi1-Inspiron-3521:8280/services/echo"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="disableREST">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="ScenarioID">scenario2</parameter>
   <enableSec/>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/EchoProxy2/services/EchoProxy2/policies/SigOnly"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Simple Proxy Service Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="CallEchoProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator="*Calling Proxy In Sequence"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"
              separator="Calling Proxy Out Sequence"/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://wi1-Inspiron-3521:8280/services/EchoProxy2"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Error in Logs:**

```
[2015-02-19 11:22:48,718] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/EchoProxy2
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:146)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 10 more
```

**Problem:**
I am unable to understand that how to pass security configurations to my simple proxy Service.So that it can communicate with the Secure Service and get back the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a secured proxy and also you have un-secured proxy. When you sent message to un-secured proxy, it must call the secured proxy. So,  your un-secured proxy must call the secured end point.  Here,  secured end point is your secured-proxy.   To call a secured end point,  you must attached a WS-Security policy in to the end point configuration.  You refer [this](http://soasecurity.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/) blog which explains how to call an secured end point.  If you follow the steps correctly,  i guess you can resolve this issue.

Comment: I followed the steps as mentioned in the blog. But i got the following error.

Comment: [2015-02-19 14:34:07,839] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot load password callback class: org.wso2.samples.pwcb.PWCBHandler

Comment: It says  "Cannot load password callback class"  Please make sure you have copied the jar file in to  correct directory and restart  the server.  Also,  please make sure class name is correct..